# How to print filtered results from django model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I am trying to print the filtered results from a django model. This is my code

```
record = StudentInfo.objects.filter(Name=name, 
                                    School=school, 
                                    City=city, 
                                    Country=country)
```

I know there are 4 entries that satisfy the filter. I now want to print the records. But when I try

```
print(record)
```

I get the following

```
[<StudentInfo: StudentInfo object (1)>, <StudentInfo: StudentInfo object (4)>, <StudentInfo: StudentInfo object (6)>, <StudentInfo: StudentInfo object (8)>]
```

How do I print the entire record as a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in your model instance `StudentInfo object (1)` is the representation of your model instance. You can change it by overriding the **str** method on your model.

```
class StudentInfo(models.Model):
    # fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

And it'll look like this.
`[<StudentInfo: StudentName>, ..]`

It's not a good approach to add all fields of your model to your **str** method.
If you want to see more info on the model instance, create another method on your model and use that.

```
class StudentInfo(models.Model):
    # fields

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

    def detail(self):
        return f"Name: {self.name}, School: {self.school} ..."
```

Print your students like this.

```
for student in record:
    print(student.detail())
```

Also, it's best practice to use all lowercase characters on your model fields. You may want to follow [`PEP-8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) rules for more info.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you question, a student can have multiple records. So it is better to use SerializerMethodField.

On your student serializer, you can do something like
(considering you have serializer for StudentInfo)

```
class StudentSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    record = serializer.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
       model = Student
       fields = "__all__" 
    def get_record(self, obj):
        record = StudentInfo.objects.filter(Name=name, 
                                    School=school, 
                                    City=city, 
                                    Country=country)
        return StudentInfoSerializer(record, many=True).data
```

after this, every time you use StudentSerializer, you will get the related record as a list.

Answer (score 1):

when you use filter() method in django it returns all results that satisfies the criteria. The result returned by filter() is called Queryset.

[<StudentInfo: StudentInfo object (1)>, <StudentInfo: StudentInfo object (4)>, <StudentInfo: StudentInfo object (6)>, <StudentInfo: StudentInfo object (8)>]

This is a queryset.
Queryset is a list of objects.

To print the results:

```
for item in record:
    print(item.Name)
    print(item.Country)
    print(item.School)
    print(item.City)
```

for one iteration of the loop one object from the queryset is taken and we are accessing its properties using dot(.)

Answer (score 0):

All the answers here require adding code to models, creating serializers, in case someone just needs to debug and see list of objects returned, I did it this way:

```py
import json
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder

print(json.dumps(list(StudentInfo.objects.filter(Name=name, School=school, City=city, Country=country).values()), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder))
```

Yeah, Django doesn't make it easy, compared to Laravel, where it's just `dd(StudentInfo.where(['Name' => name, 'School' => school, 'City' => city, 'Country' => country]));` with a beautiful colored output.